# What is the difference of "committee" and "commission"?

Tags: word-choice

They are similar in meanings and they may be interchangeable? Because they both mean the body that exists for long-term or short term tasks or purposes, formed with professional or non-professional people. It is hard for users to decide which one to be used in a particular context.

Comment: You posted this question and I answered it two days ago

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145591/is-%E5%A7%94%E5%91%98%E4%BC%9A-a-commission-or-a-committee

Comment: I didn't realize that these two sites are related and that you are a regular visitors of both sites. And I wanted to know about the answer from dfferent points of view. The first one is from Chinese language point and the other or current one is from English language point.

Comment: Hi, that question you posted is on this exact same site: English Language Learners StackExchange. But yes, I was wondering why there was so much (or any) Chinese in your question. But I figured I had enough information about the question, so just answered it anyway.

Comment: @Ringo Oh, it is a big mistake, that one containing Chinese words should have been posted in the Chinese language site, could the admin move it there? I am very sorry to cause such troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Insofar as we're only talking about the definition of each word that refers to some group of people and not other potential definitions, yes, they're mostly interchangeable.

Both words tend to suggest some political context but don't necessarily require it.

One slight different shade in meaning is that commissions are often – though not always – set up for some specific task and then disbanded after they've served their purpose. That's why, of the three different varieties of the group-of-people definition [Merriam-Webster lists](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commission) for "committee," the first is

> a group of persons directed to perform some duty.

M-W's example sentence for that meaning is a pretty good one to illustrate this idea (emphasis mine):

> The state *set up* a commission to study the proposed merger of the school districts.

Whereas the state might have a standing **committee** on, say, school finance or K–12 education, which would be responsible for reviewing legislation and policy under its purview whenever necessary, the state may, by contrast, form a temporary **commission** for considering the proposed school district merger, and then that commission would disband after giving its recommendation on whether or not the merger should happen.

But again, these are just tendencies. Where I live, the political leadership of the city is called the city *commission*, not the city committee, even though they are a standing body for all political matters, not a specially assembled group for one particular purpose.

I think the best practical advice I can give is to try to find out if, in the particular context you're discussing, there already exists some preference for either "committee" or "commission" and, if not, just pick one.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear and your advice is very practical, thanks.